# open pdf in IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, pdf, internet-explorer

I need to open the pdf file in IE Browser. Is there any way we can achieve that.This works only in chrome

```
var byteCharacters = atob(response.data);
var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
  byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
var file = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf;base64' });
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
window.open(fileURL);
```

Comment: Yes now its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support `URL.createObjectURL()`. IE has its own API for creating and downloading files, which is called `msSaveBlob` or `msSaveOrOpenBlob`. The difference between the `msSaveBlob` and `msSaveOrOpenBlob` methods is that the former only provides a **Save** button to the user whereas the latter provides both a **Save** and an **Open** button.

Besides, IE doesn't have PDF viewer embeded, so you can't display PDFs directly in IE 11. You can only use [msSaveOrOpenBlob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/hh779016(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to handle blobs in IE, then choose to open or save the PDF file:

```
if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    //IE11
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobData, fileName); 
}
else{
   //Other browsers
    window.URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
    ...
}
```